# MvcBuildViews ignore ascx and aspx and compile only cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, sitecore

In a Siteocre project I want to compile all cshtml files using the MvcBuildViews setting. Unfortunately this also compiles any ascx and aspx files. I get an error like :

> 32>/temp/Sitecore/admin/Wizard/InstallationLog.ascx(1): error
>   ASPPARSE: The base class includes the field 'logPanel', but its type
>   (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) is not compatible with
>   the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe).

Is there a way to restrict the view compilation to cshtml only?

Comment: Can you exclude from your project Sitecore files? It's a bad practice to have all Sitecore files in your project. Put in your project just Sitecore file you are overriding.

Comment: they are not in my csproj project atm. It is in the same folder though which causes the issue. It seems the aspnetcompiler compiles all files in a folder

Answer (score -1):

I will transform my comment into an answer.

Your approach to have Sitecore inside your Visual Studio folder is not correct.

You need to separate your Visual Studio and website folder where IIS is mapping your site.

On next link is explained very well how to create a Visual Studio Project for Sitecore MVC .

http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/sitecore-mvc/creating-project/